# How eliminate duplicate cases from a switch statement in PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement, micro-optimization

I'm making a function to return whether or not the given `user_id` is a staff member of the site. This is what I have and it works, however I feel like it can be greatly improved.

```
public function isUserStaff($uid) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_role FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':user_id'=>$uid));
    $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $role = $userRow['user_role'];

    switch($role) {
        case 3:
            return true;
            break;
        case 4:
            return true;
            break;
        case 5:
            return true;
            break;
        case 6:
            return true;
            break;
        case 7:
            return true;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
            break;
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me out and describe how I can make my code better. I think there are too many `case`'s and I'm looking for something smaller to use.

Comment: Done @AlexanderO'Mara

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have `switch` cases that are the same, you can combine them by omitting the `return` and `break` lines of the earlier cases.

In the following, `3`, `4`, `5` and `6` all take the `return` value of case `7` (`true`):

```
switch($role) {
    case 3:
    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
        return true;
        break;
    default:
        return false;
        break;
}
```

Although having said that, considering **everything** seems to return the same way apart from your default, you might be better off making use of a simple `if` condition. You can even specify that the roles should be between 3 and 7:

```
if ($role >= 3 && $role <= 7) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I didn't know you could do that, it certainly helps! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

A lookup array can be used to eliminate condition statements.
Because `in_array()` is much slower than `isset()` it is advisable to set up your lookup are to store values as keys.

Code:

```
public function isUserStaff($uid) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_role FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':user_id'=>$uid));
    $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $lookup=[3=>'',4=>'',5=>'',6=>'',7=>'']; // or array_flip(range(3,7))
    return isset($lookup[$userRow['user_role']]);
}
```

This solution becomes even more useful when your identifying values are non-sequential -- you just list them in an array: `$lookup=[3=>'',6=>'',9=>''];` This approach is very easy to maintain as your requirements grow/change.

Lastly, you don't need to write `break` after a `return` because the `return` halts all actions inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

Ternary operator - all in one line:

```
public function isUserStaff($uid){
    $stmt=$this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_role FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':user_id'=>$uid));
    $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    return $userRow['user_role']<3 && $userRow['user_role']>7 ? false : true;
}
```

Comment: Looks clean, but throws `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'return'`

Comment: This is not something you should do to production code. This is difficult to read quickly.

Comment: And if you're going to return a boolean, just flip the logic and return the result of the expression. `return $userRow['user_role'] >= 3 && $userRow['user_role'] <= 7;`

Comment: Already edited. Ternary operators are perfectly valid, that's why they exist. Legibility is the individual's issue.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`in_array`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) like this:

```
public function isUserStaff($uid) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT user_role FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':user_id'=>$uid));
    $userRow = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $role = $userRow['user_role'];

    return in_array($role, [
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7
    ], true);
}
```